# почему строку определяет как число?

Tags: python

'x' проходит это проверку будучи значением "a-z"
что не так?

```
x = input()
if type(x) == type(6) or type(6.6):
print('x - int')
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что нужно писать не так:

```
if type(x) == type(6) or type(6.6):
```

А вот так:

```
if type(x) == type(6) or type(x) == type(6.6):
```

Но лучше вообще писать вот так:

```
if isinstance(x, int) or isinstance(x, float):
```

Comment: `isinstance(x, (int, float))`